# How to detect missing dot-dot-dot in generic function argument

Tags: r, missing-data

Suppose I have a function like

```
z <- function(x, ...) {
  print(x)
}
```

If `...` is missing, the function should do one thing; if `...` is specified, the function should do something else with it. In this case I can use `missing(...)` to detect if `..` is missing. But I don't find an elegant way to detect with generic methods like `[.Obj(x, ...)` where missing `...` is still a `pairlist(<emptyname>)` and `missing(...) = FALSE` even if I don't give values.

Here are some experiments:

```
z <- function(x, ...) {
  cat(missing(...))
}

Obj <- function() {
  env <- environment()
  class(env) <- "Obj"
  env
}

`[.Obj` <- function(x,...) {
  cat(missing(...),"\n")
}
```

With the above code evaluate the following:

```
> z()
TRUE
> z(a=1)
FALSE
> Obj()[]
FALSE 
NULL
> Obj()[a=1]
FALSE 
NULL
```

However, in debug mode for `Obj()[]` in RStudio, it is like

```
Browse[1]> list(...)
Error: argument is missing, with no default
Browse[1]> missing(...)
[1] FALSE
```

Somehow the way that works for `z()` does not work for `Obj()[]`. Is there an elegant way with little overhead to detect whether `...` is missing for the `[.Obj(x, ...)` case which I actually encounter?

See also: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Arguments-passing-through-dot-dot-dot-lose-ability-to-check-for-missing-td4656455.html

Comment: Can you just use `missing(...)`?

Comment: @GSee It does not work for [.Obj(x,...) case.

Comment: Currently, my best solution is `if(any(nzchar(substitute(...))))` in case where `Obj()[f(x)]`

Comment: Or maybe `if (length(list=...) == 0 )`  ?

Answer (score 3):

Try checking if `..1` is missing:

```
> `[.Obj` <- function(x, ...) missing(..1)
> Obj()[a=1]
[1] FALSE
> Obj()[]
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Curiously ..0 also seems to work, being the same as ..1, but I can't find this documented in the R-intro.pdf where ... and ..1 etc are documented...

Comment: @Spacedman I tried it, and `..0` references the same argument as `..1` . Sounds like an "undocumented feature" aka "BUG"  .

Comment: Just checked the source. ..1 etc works via nthcdr in util.c - if the number is less than 1 the loop walking down ... short-circuits. You can do `..-2` if you backquote it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this does not work with `Obj()[,y]` or similar cases which are used in `data.table` like `as.data.table(mtcars)[,mean(mpg)]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
`[.Obj` <- function(x,...) {
  length(as.list(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE))[-c(1,2)])==1L
}
```

Noting that for some functions (such as `[.data.frame`) an *empty* argument is not the same as the argument not being there (ie being missing).